# How to stop "Opto Host" taking over a port (Linux)

Tags: centos, firewalld

I have added two rules in firewalld, using the following commands:

`firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=22005/tcp --permanent`

`firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=22003/udp --permanent`

After reloading firewalld, I took a look at iptables, with `iptables -L`

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:optohost005 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:optohost003 ctstate NEW
```

What is `optohost`, and why does it replace `22`? I can't find much about this anywhere on Google. It only seems to happen for these two IPs (22005/22003)

I am running CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611, 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64

firewalld 0.4.3.2

Update:

After some more searching, I found this:

http://sysconfcollect.sourceforge.net/examples/scc.docker_centos7.html

```
optohost003     22003/tcp               # Opto Host Port 3
optohost003     22003/udp               # Opto Host Port 3
optohost005     22005/tcp               # Opto Host Port 5
optohost005     22005/udp               # Opto Host Port 5
```

This is documentation for "docker", more specifically the contents of `/etc/services` which I checked manually on my machine and the lines exist. I'm not exactly sure what "docker" does but I know it's something to do with my network.. If I check `ifconfig`, sure enough it's there:

```
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
    ether 02:42:d2:8b:6d:b6  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

What I gather from this is that docker has some services running on those ports (22005/22003) and it's taking over (?)

I need these ports for a game server that I run. Any idea on how to stop it from "taking over" those ports?

Update #2: Removing those lines from `/etc/services` makes `optohost` disappear when looking up the ports with `iptables -L`, and the ports are displayed correctly. However I am not entirely sure what effect removing those lines has, and if it has any actual effect at all apart from simply being a label or name.

Comment: Since your actual question has changed, consider updating the title to better reflect the question.